# Too many rows - PHPMyAdmin Table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I wanted to show all rows on same page, so I just typed 9999999 in number rows.
Now I get this error:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\DisplayResults.class.php on line 2827
Is it possible to set the amount of rows to load down without entering the page - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested with phpMyAdmin 4.3 and this is stored in the session -- by logging out and logging back in again, this value should get reset to whatever default you have (controlled by [`$cfg['MaxRows']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxRows) in `config.inc.php`, by default 25).